# Refactor the if statement in the editor to use a ternary operator

Tags: ruby

Is my solution correct here? CodeAcademy returns the following error: **" Oops, try again. Make sure your 'if' statement still has the same behavior. It should puts 'One is less than two!'**

```
if 1 < 2
  puts "One is less than two!"
else
  puts "One is not less than two."
end


# My Solution 
# 1 < 2 ? "One is less than two!" : "One is not less than two"
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your solution has `puts`, so it's not outputting. You may also need to put parens around 1 < 2.

Comment: As esel pointed out you are just missing the puts. Since this is being checked by a program it may want something specific. You can try `puts (1 < 2 ? "One is less than two!" : "One is not less than two")` and if it doesn't like it then try `1 < 2 ? puts "One is less than two!" : puts "One is not less than two"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
puts "One is less than two!" if 1 < 2 : "One is not less than two."
```

Comment: That's not syntactically valid Ruby and the assignment was to use a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
puts 1 < 2 ? "One is less than two!" : "One is not less than two."
```

you start with the boolean statement then for some odd reason puts comes first (dont really understand the logic behind that but ok) then you do this if its true, colon spereated then do this if false.